# How can i give a download link to the thumbnail or featured image

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am using the code below to give users download the thumbnail image,  as i have a wallpapers site:

```
<a class="downloadbutton" href="<?php echo $src[0]; ?>" download="imageName">Download this Wallpaper</a>
```

But the above code is giving download of a htm file not the image download, can anyone please help me solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify. You want to link a thumbnail/featured image to a file which users can download? Or you want to add a link to a file which is a image?

Comment: i want to download the thumbnail and i m using this function in my custom post type, and yes it is an image .jpg

Comment: close voting as if the file being opened is an html, either the link is not to an image or there is some sever configuration problem

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file to your Media Library and link to it using HTML anywhere in your theme.

```
<a href="http://www.example.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/logo.jpg">Download this image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems ok, but make sure the $src[0] is giving the full url to the image as:"http://www.yoursite.com/your_upload_folder/imagename.jpg" with extension

check the value of the $src[0] to make sure it's giving the full url to the image and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$thumbnailSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full', false );
<a download="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php echo $thumbnailSrc[0]; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Use this in your archive file.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?